# printWritter issue in Java

Tags: java, printwriter

I have a question regarding to printWrttier with String output, here is my code:

```
     import java.io.File;
     import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
     import java.io.PrintWriter;
     import java.util.Scanner;


    public class Out {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                File a=new File("C:/Users/Acer/Desktop/tyty.txt");
                PrintWriter out=new PrintWriter(a);
                Scanner c=new Scanner(System.in);
                while(c.hasNextLine()) {
                    out.printf("%s",c.nextLine());
                }
                c.close();
                out.close();
                System.out.println("input written into file successfully!");
            } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("The file not found");
            }
        }
    }
```

However, when I input some random String such as a b c d in the console, it has no response at all, I expect it to print out "input written into file successfully!", then I can see my input is shown up in the text file, but which part in my code cause the error?

P.S the ctrl+c is not working here, as it is not killing the loop.

Comment: Flush the stream using out.flush() and then close

Answer (score 1):

Flush the stream using out.flush(), else use autoflush. See javadocs

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter(java.io.OutputStream, boolean)

Comment: Sotirios, control does not reach till close unless eol(end-of-line) terminator is passed as argument.

Use EOL terminator or flush everytime you write (bad idea)

Answer (score 1):

An end of line terminator is required for the `while` loop to exit. On Windows this is Control-Z, for *nix systems, Control-D

In addition match `nextLine` with `hasNextLine`

```
while(c.hasNextLine()){
    out.printf("%s",c.nextLine());
}
```

...you might want to move those `close` statements into a `finally` block to guard against any exceptions within the `try/catch` block

Comment: Hi, I have tried your code, but same thing, so how can I exit the loop ?

Comment: @Wang Pei The Dancer Your program will process the entire input stream in one shot. As the answers here point out, your program will block until that input is ready (ctrl z or d). If you want line by line processing, look at event based programming techniques such as listening for keyboard events.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from Reimeus

> An end of line terminator is required for the while loop to exit. On Windows this is Control-C, for *nix systems, Control-D

You got to press the following buttons when you think you are done with the input in the console
1) Cntrl+C - if running in windows machine
2) Cntrl+D - if running in Linux (*nix) machine

```
C:\Users\somone\Desktop>java Out
something
is
better
than
nothing
input written into file successfully!
```

I pressed 'Cntrl+C' after typing 'nothing'

Answer (score 0):

For Eclipse use 'Cntrl+Z'.

Better add a
 `System.out.println("Please Input the lines that needs to be written in the file \n ");`

above the `While` statement